# How to display record in custom created related list of all users having same manager in servicenow

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I want to display the record in custom created related list of all users having saming manager in servicenow. For e.g. Abel, Jack has manager Adel, so when I open Adel record I should be able to see the Abel user and Jack user.

This is the script I used and don't know how it will execute in related list:

```
var gr = new GlideRecord('sys_user');
gr.addQuery('user_name','abel');
gr.query();
gr.next();
gs.print(gr.getDisplayValue('manager'));
```

I tried this is in Scripts Background option in Application Navigator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to code for this.  If you want to add a related list of user's the current user manages.  It will list as "Users" but you can change that label in the related list configuration.

[image: Open menu to add related lists]
[image: Add the related list]

If you meant to do this by code, you'd need to a scripted relationship the data.  Here's some information on that.  https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/newyork-platform-user-interface/page/administer/form-administration/task/t_CreateDefinedRelatedLists.html